# Who has been using MMDrawerController, gestures conflict how to solve

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, mmdrawercontroller

I want to use `MMDrawerController` in my project.My home page has a `Scrollview` and two `tableview` in scrollview.So left slide and right slide MMDrawerController not work.please help me .I saw [self.drawerController.centerViewController myCustomSubview] is solve this problem？I don't know myCustomSubview what this is?

Answer (score 0):

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` provides methods for managing gesture conflicts, and UIScrollView exposes the gestures that are used so you can provide more fine grained control.

If you combine those with `setGestureShouldRecognizeTouchBlock` on drawerController, you should be able to manage the conflict.

Anyway this can't only be achieved with the `setGestureShouldRecognizeTouchBlock`.
You can achieve it using `shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer` to actually disable the scrollview gesture.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer != self.panGesture || self.openSide != MMDrawerSideNone) {
        return NO;
    }
    CGPoint velocity = [self.panGesture velocityInView:self.panGesture.view];
    BOOL isHorizontalGesture = fabs(velocity.y) <= fabs(velocity.x);

    if(isHorizontalGesture) {
        CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
    if(([self isPointContainedWithinLeftBezelRect:point] && self.leftDrawerViewController) ||
       ([self isPointContainedWithinRightBezelRect:point] && self.rightDrawerViewController)){
            otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
            otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```